# Ubuntu FQDN Not pingable on Windows Network

Tags: networking, 13.04, windows, dns, dhcp

My problem is that my Ubuntu machine seems to have its FQDN setup correctly, yet I cannot ping the FQDN from a windows machine on the same network.

Output of various commands on my Ubuntu machine:

```
hostname    : test
hostname -d : testdomain.com
hostname -f : test.testdomain.com
```

My Ubuntu version is 13.04.

Relevant line in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.1.1     test.testdomain.com test
```

Hosts line from /etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
hosts:        files dns
```

Line from  /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf:

```
send host-name = gethostname();
```

Now, my network uses Windows DNS servers and I found this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1088682) that contains what looks like a relevant issue. It was fixed in isc-dhcp - 4.2.4-1ubuntu10.2

Ubuntu 13.04 comes with 4.2.4-5ubuntu2

My question is: 
How do I get this to work so that the Windows DNS Server gets successfully updated with the IP address and FQDN of the ubuntu machine?

Comment: Having a DNS resolve `test.testdomain.com` to `127.0.0.1` runs afoul of the convention that `127.0.0.1` means `localhost`, that is "this computer right here".

Comment: that line was created by the Ubuntu installer.